# Symfony2 multiple embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have 3 linked entities :
Profil can have many competences, and each competences can have many specialities. This result by this schema :
Profil -> OneToMany -> competences -> OneToMany -> Specialities.

In my Profil form, i want to be able to list all competences with checkbox, and for each competence, list all specialities also with checkbox (all competences may have the same specialities), like this :

```
> Profil form view :
Comptences :
   [] competence-A
          [] specialite-A
          [] specialite-B
          [] specialite-C
   [] competence-B
          [] specialite-A
          [] specialite-B
          [] specialite-C
   [] competence-C
          [] specialite-A
          [] specialite-B
          [] specialite-C
   [] competence-D
          [] specialite-A
          [] specialite-B
          [] specialite-C
...
```

I tried to use entity field type, but i can't link a sub level of specialities, and i also tried collection field type, but it only show my competences, not all of the database.
Any idea ?